# line feeds in FileSaver.js

Tags: javascript, filesaver.js

I'm trying FileSaver.js but when saving as text all of the linefeeds are gone. I've read good things about FileSaver.js but losing all of the line feeds so it is just one long text string is a deal breaker.  I always assume that I'm doing something wrong first so I figured I'd ask.  If you go to the demo https://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/ you can see the saving Text sample and if you put in 1 Enter 2 Enter 3 enter 4 enter etc it all comes out on a horizontal line. Any ideas are appreciated.  I was wondering if any one else has had experience with this?  Do I need to save it as xhtml?  I'm using type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8" just like the demo

Comment: are you receiving any errors in console? the demo appears to preserve line feeds when using their plain text, what browser and os are you using?

Comment: OS Windows 7 I've tried IE, Chrome and Firefox-- all the same  I enter
1 {enter}
2  {enter}
3  {enter}
4  {enter}
(Only way I can show here the linefeeds)
and get 1234 in the downloaded file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use notepad to open the .txt files? For me the filesaver seems to be working. Try using [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), notepad is limited in recognizing linebreaks from different OS systems (and the server is probably linux).

Notepad only recognises CR, LF (0x0d, 0x0a), whereas other sources might use CR only, or LF only.

Comment: The demo works fine with my Mac using Safari but not Windows and notepad.  Opened with Word and it was fine.  Guess I need to tweak my file before sending to save

Comment: My problem is that I've build this into an app by saving a simple text web page and saving it as .txt.  Most people when then get a file will just double click to open.  I guess I need to do some find and replace before I call the save as function